# Order by Two Elements in xQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm very new to xQuery and I've to write the query to do the following;

> Display books and articles sorted by year.

I tried the following;

```
for $b in doc("myDB.xml")/myDB
order by $b/book/year, $b/article/year
return $b/book, $b/article
```

or

```
for $b in doc("myDB.xml")/myDB
order by $b//year
return $b/book, $b/article
```

and it's not sorting anything.

XML is;

```
<myDB>
    <book>
        <title>ebXML : Concepts and Application</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
            <first_name>Brian</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <publisher>Wiley</publisher>
    </book>

    <article>
        <title>test title</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
            <first_name>Brian</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <publisher>test Wiley</publisher>
    </article>

    <book>
        <title>XML: Visual QuickStart Guide</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Goldberg</last_name>
            <first_name>Kevin</first_name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last_name>Doe</last_name>
            <first_name>John</first_name>
        </author>

        <year>2008</year>
        <publisher>Peachpit Press</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Beginning XML</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Hunter</last_name>
            <first_name>David</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2007</year>
        <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Learning XML </title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Ray</last_name>
            <first_name>Erik</first_name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last_name>Smith</last_name>
            <first_name>David</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Professional XML</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Evjen</last_name>
            <first_name>Bill</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2007</year>
        <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
    </book>
    <article>
        <title>FileNet Integrates a New XML Editor for Non-Techies</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Roe</last_name>
            <first_name>David</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>CMS Wire</journal>
        <year>2009</year>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>The Groundbreaking Potential of Codeless Ajax</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Dusoe</last_name>
            <first_name>Jim</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>Tech News World</journal>
        <year>2009</year>
        <pages>4</pages>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>Windows and .NET Watch: Recognizing DSL opportunities</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>O'Brien</last_name>
            <first_name>Larry</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>Software Development Times</journal>
        <year>2009</year>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>An embedded XML Database: Oracle Berkeley DB XML</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
            <first_name>Brian</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>The Register</journal>
        <year>2003</year>
        <pages>8</pages>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>Open Source PostgreSQL 8.3 Better Suited For Web Applications </title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Babcock</last_name>
            <first_name>Charles</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>Information Week</journal>
        <year>2008</year>
        <pages>1</pages>
    </article>
</myDB>
```

The output is the whole xml itself followed by the books and articles elements in the original order.

Do I really need a FOR for that? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

```
let $doc := doc("Your.xml)/myDB
for $eachBook in $doc/child::*
order by $eachBook/year
return $eachBook
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <title>ebXML : Concepts and Application</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
      <first_name>Brian</first_name>
    </author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <publisher>Wiley</publisher>
  </book>
<article>
    <title>test title</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
      <first_name>Brian</first_name>
    </author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <publisher>test Wiley</publisher>
  </article>
<book>
    <title>Learning XML </title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Ray</last_name>
      <first_name>Erik</first_name>
    </author>
    <author>
      <last_name>Smith</last_name>
      <first_name>David</first_name>
    </author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
<article>
    <title>An embedded XML Database: Oracle Berkeley DB XML</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
      <first_name>Brian</first_name>
    </author>
    <journal>The Register</journal>
    <year>2003</year>
    <pages>8</pages>
  </article>
<book>
    <title>Beginning XML</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Hunter</last_name>
      <first_name>David</first_name>
    </author>
    <year>2007</year>
    <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
  </book>
<book>
    <title>Professional XML</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Evjen</last_name>
      <first_name>Bill</first_name>
    </author>
    <year>2007</year>
    <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
  </book>
<book>
    <title>XML: Visual QuickStart Guide</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Goldberg</last_name>
      <first_name>Kevin</first_name>
    </author>
    <author>
      <last_name>Doe</last_name>
      <first_name>John</first_name>
    </author>

    <year>2008</year>
    <publisher>Peachpit Press</publisher>
  </book>
<article>
    <title>Open Source PostgreSQL 8.3 Better Suited For Web Applications </title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Babcock</last_name>
      <first_name>Charles</first_name>
    </author>
    <journal>Information Week</journal>
    <year>2008</year>
    <pages>1</pages>
  </article>
<article>
    <title>FileNet Integrates a New XML Editor for Non-Techies</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Roe</last_name>
      <first_name>David</first_name>
    </author>
    <journal>CMS Wire</journal>
    <year>2009</year>
  </article>
<article>
    <title>The Groundbreaking Potential of Codeless Ajax</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>Dusoe</last_name>
      <first_name>Jim</first_name>
    </author>
    <journal>Tech News World</journal>
    <year>2009</year>
    <pages>4</pages>
  </article>
<article>
    <title>Windows and .NET Watch: Recognizing DSL opportunities</title>
    <author>
      <last_name>O'Brien</last_name>
      <first_name>Larry</first_name>
    </author>
    <journal>Software Development Times</journal>
    <year>2009</year>
  </article>
```

Comment: Have you changed doc("Your.xml), you need to put URI of your XML file. Or you may pass your myDB node into $doc

Comment: yes i changed it to doc("myDB.xml") that is the name of my xml. It didn't work. Doing let $doc := /myDB gives an error; [XPST0003] Incomplete location step.

Comment: If you are usking doc("Your.xml), your XML and XQUERY must be in the same folder/path. You may also check by trying to return $doc first, it is getting any node or not.

Comment: Yes I have an idea about it. The statement let $doc := doc("myDB.xml")/myDB return $doc is returning the whole xml

Comment: Then it shoult work. I also posted generated output with this XQUERY, have a look

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28667/discussion-between-nommyravian-and-navin-rawat)

Comment: btw, it is BaseX, not xBase (I guess thats what you meant as I have never heard of an xml processor called xBase...)

Comment: It worked in Oxygen, I don't know what was the problem with BaseX. Thanks you

Comment: Sounds very much like BaseX was looking for the document at another location than you expected. It works fine on my machine using BaseX. Feel free to also ask for support on our BaseX mailing list (as this kind of setup questions i not really suited for SO) if you have further troubles setting up BaseX.